# OS X does not recognize keyboard and trackpad while Boot Camp Windows still can

Tags: macos, keyboard, mac, bootcamp

I've encountered strange issues on my Macbook Air 2013.

1. I spilled some drop of water on keyboard (near trackpad and spacebar)
2. I did some cleaning, and then try to boot again.
3. The OS X then can not detect my keyboard and trackpad. I was unable to log in.
4. But still I'm able to press button to reset PRAM and SMC, but nothing changes.
5. I decided to wait, after a few hours, I booted it again and this time the Fan start to run at (seem to be) max speed without any heavy task (I wasn't able to log in).
6. I tried to boot Windows 8 on the Boot Camp partition, surprisingly it works, trackpad and keyboard are fine. I'm writing this from windows.
7. So I thought maybe I should re-install OS X like someone said on this forum. but the installation also denied to recognize the keyboard, so I stop installing.

Could you help me to make the OS X recognize my keyboard, trackpad and stop my fan from sounding like a helicopter?

Edit: I ran an AHT and it told me I have SMC error code PFM006, which I heard to be related to thermal sensor. I'll probably bring to a store to fix...

Answer (score 1):

You could try the SMC reset. Option-Command (⌘)-P-R

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14222

Also try start in safe mode, that does some repairs. (hold Shift)

Try using external keyboard.

Finlay use the OSX restore function to restore your OSX.  (Command(⌘)-R)

Maybe lesson learned and buy a cheep keyboard cover in the future.

Comment: thanks. I tried SMC reset and safe mode but nothing changed. External keyboard works but the fan still goes crazy. I actually have a cover but the keyboard is too good to be covered :)

Answer (score 0):

Dry it out for a few hours in a warm place and see what happens :)